# How to set title of \listoftables and \listoffigures to sans serif

Tags: table-of-contents, sans-serif

I have a page in my book document with just the commands `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`. However, I want the respective titles - that is 'List of Tables' and 'List of Figures' to show up using the default sans serif font that I've already set. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `\def\listfigurename{\textsc{List of Figures}}`

Comment: In the preamble? That doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Unless you provide a minimal working example, we can't actually test anything.